# React Router v6.14.0: Getting 404 on refresh & writing manually URL (using createBrowserRouter)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using routes with `createBrowserRouter` and everything is fine locally but when I upload my website build and make my site live, when I enter the url manually or refresh the page, I'm getting `404 Error`, I've researched on various stack questions but didn't get the answer on how exactly solve this issue when you're using `createBrowserRouter` instead of `<Routes> //Routes here </Routes>`.

I also tried [spa-github-pages](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages) where you make 404.html file in `/public` and copy the script mentioned in the github repo, but this solution also didn't work.

I'm using a simple method of routing with latest [react-router version](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router). I know its a `client side routing` issue but how to solve it exactly with **react-router v6.14.0**

Also another problem is when I get 404 Not Found error I can't see my `<404NotPage />` well designed component page.

Here is my code:-

App.js

```
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([ 
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: "about-us",
    element: <About />,
  },
  {
    path: "*",
    element: <NotFound />, // also can't see this page
  },
])

export default function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

Comment: How are you building the app and where are you deploying it to? Each server/hosting service likely has different requirements. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's already a relevant section for what you are using.

Comment: Im using regular method using `npm run build` command for build and Im uploading that build on cpanel, my site is working fine unless I refresh or enter the url manually. Also please note its a static site with dynamic forms only, and Im not using any .env, express, or any API integration in the project.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with cpanel (*never heard of it, actually*), but I did manage to find [how to install a node.js application](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/) documentation. Other than this it appears they utilize Apache servers so you may be able to fiddle with the `.htaccess` as per the CRA deployment docs I linked you to previously.

Comment: Yes thank you, it's working now, I've created `.htaccess` file and added below mentioned code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.htaccess` file and add below code if you are hosting your build on Apache server (cpanel)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteBase /  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l  
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this worked for me:

```
  {
    path: "/*",
    element: <NotFound />
  }
```